# Openldap installation on ubuntu server 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to install openldap on ubuntu server 10.04 following this article:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenLDAPServer

However `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd` is pretty useless as it only gives me this:
-Omit OpenLDAP server configuration? **No**
-Do you want the database to be removed when slapd is purged? **No**
-Allow LDAPv2 protocol? **No**

I was expecting more, like be able to create the database, but apparently this is an issue that was recently introduced:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/442498

Can someone give me the directions as to how setting up openldap please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the administrator guide is slightly out of date, especially since OpenLDAP is moving toward the cn=config style configuration, instead of the flat-file based slapd.conf.  I'm still working on setting one up myself, but here are some resources I've found that make life a little easier:

http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html
http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2010/05/openldap-ubuntu-linux.html
http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2010/06/openldap-password-permissions-config.html

And this one, which goes hand-in-hand with the last link above:
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201002/msg00181.html

I mention that, because the only documentation on OpenLDAP's site regarding the memberOf overlay is geared toward the old flat-file config and hasn't been updated for the new style.  It's rather frustrating trying to track down accurate documentation for OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [official OpenLDAP Administrator's Guide Quickstart](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html)?

Comment: I started looking at this in the meantime. I wasn't aware but in order to compile, Berkeley DB needs to be installed, otherwise `./configure` gives an **configure: error: BDB/HDB: BerkeleyDB not available** error. And guess who owns BerkeleyDB? Oracle...: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html. They are slowly taking over the good opensource bits (MySQL,OpenOffice...)

Comment: Is there a problem using the Ubuntu-supplied OpenLDAP and related binaries or do you want to compile from source for some specific reason? If you don't need to compile from source just use the Ubuntu packages and jump to configuring slapd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow steps on this link: [OpenLDAP installation steps on Ubuntu 10.10 (french)](http://www.aepik.net/documentation/annuaire/openldap/installation). It is in french, but commands are universal, and you will be able to run an operationnal openldap server quickly (as I do successfully).